# How to bind numbers to DataGridComboBoxColumn without duplicate Values in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am working on the sample application, where I have DataGrid with say 5 rows and 2 Columns. 2nd column is the DataGridComboBoxColumn which signifies say priority of the 1st column. So user can select the priority of the 5 rows from the comboboxes in the 2nd column. We have to bind the list containing 1 to 6 numbers to the DataGridComboBoxColumn.

The problem is that if 1st ComboBox is selected 1, then it should not appear in the remaining ComboBoxes. Same for the remaining ComboBoxes also. Just give me at least some hint how to achieve it. I am using C#, WPF

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: One might argue that a list the user can reorder would be better UI. Are you saying the combos will start with no selection? what if the user makes a mistake or changes her mind? You'd have to reset and make them start over.

Comment: @Crowcoder If I directly bind the list or ObservableCollection to DataGridComboBoxColumn, they may select the same number more than once. So I would like to do so...

Comment: Then I don't understand because you also say "...should not appear in the remaining ComboBoxes"

Comment: I agree with @Crowcoder that Orderable List would be better UI for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data trigger

```
      <Style x:Key="SingleSelectionComboBoxItem" TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
                    <!-- Hide it -->
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <!-- Also prevent user from selecting it via arrows or mousewheel -->
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

so your Combobox will be like :

```
                                <ComboBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SingleSelectionComboBoxItem}" Path=Selection}"  SelectionChanged="SingleSelectionComboBox_SelectionChanged" DisplayMemberPath = "Number"/>
```

Code-Behind:

```
 private void SingleSelectionComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems.OfType<PopolazioneCombo>())
        {
            item.Selected = false;
        }

        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems.OfType<PopolazioneCombo>())
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Then you defined a class in your ViewModel like this:

```
    public class ComboBoxPopulation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    private bool selected = false;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return selezionato; }
        set
        {
            if (selezionato != value)
            {
                selezionato = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your Item source will be like :

```
 public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxPopulation> Selezione
    {
        get
        {
            return selezione;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selezione != value)
            {
                selezione = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Selezione");
            }
        }
    }
```